# MessageBox on the top from all threads

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

When the application starts, splash screen is shown from another thread.
But, in case an error during start up - message box will be shown. The problem is: messagebox is shown under the splash. I have used IWin32Window owner property, even tried to use MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly property, but id did not help.

How can I manage this situation ?

PS: 
Tried to create invisible window, set TopMost - and show MessageBox. Did not work.

Comment: You shouldn't use another thread than UI to show Windows(Form,MessageBox,SplashScreen etc)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: That's not universally true. You're allowed to use a distinct thread for each window.

Comment: @Douglas that will be good for argument but not reality! I know window is having 1->1 relationship with thread which it was created, but you can't create dedicated thread for each window you create

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Not only *can* you create a dedicated thread per window, but you actually *should* do so if your application's UI consists of more than a few basic elements. The manycore era will be with us in a few years, and applications that continue to run a bulk of their processing on a single thread will soon become deprecated.

Comment: @Douglas Sounds good, Lets see :)

Comment: Make the Splash screen display the popup.  You must have a reference to it already since you close it when the main form loads.  Don't forget to marshal the call with Invoke() since you're dealing with multiple threads and the UI.

Comment: @Douglas where is your reference for your recommendation to use a new thread for any UI with "more than few basic elements"?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with an application with multiple UI threads (if done right).  If you want to have one form/messagebox "on top of them all" then they'll all have to have the same owner and the form/messagebox will need to be on that owner's thread.

Answer (score 2):

I created a similar situation using multi-threading and used this code to keep the MessageBox on top of the window. Basically this code makes the message box top most.

```
MessageBox.Show(this,
    "Your text",
    "Settings Needed",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
    MessageBoxIcon.Question,
    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
    (MessageBoxOptions)0x40000); // this is MB_TOPMOST flag
```